# Select where and where not

Tags: sql, database, select

I have a table containing lessons that I called "cours" (french) and I have several cours inside and I have linked them to students with a table between them to see if they go to the lessons or not.

I would like to return data with the SELECT and the data that are NOT select.

So, If one student follow 3 courses of 5, I would like to return the 3 courses that he follow and the 2 courses that he doesn't follow.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will vary based on your RBDMS, but something similar to the following should work:

```
SELECT
    s.Name,
    l.Name,
    CASE WHEN sl.StudentID IS NULL 
        THEN 'Not Follows' 
        ELSE 'Follows' 
    END AS Status
FROM
    Student s
    CROSS JOIN Lessons l
    LEFT JOIN Student_Lessons sl
        ON s.ID = sl.StudentID
        AND l.ID = sl.LessonID
```

Comment: Thanks you, that really helped me. I learned a new think today !

Answer (score 0):

this is an `outer join`.  if you identify your database engine (which may have specific outer join syntax) and your schema, then you can get some help with the actual SQL.